# Which service to use to host Group Projects?

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio, c#-4.0

Well I intend to host the group projects assigned by my Professor to a service like GitHub or CodePlex. I even have made an account on CodePlex to get started. What I am confused about is which is the most easiest to use for beginners like me or my Team members. Moreover which source control system to use with Visual Studio 2010 Professional? Any links or tutorials will be helpful for me.

Plus: Which license to use for Personal Projects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using VS Professional and working in a team, then I suggest trying [Team Foundation Server](http://codeplex.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Using%20TFS%20and%20Team%20Explorer%20with%20CodePlex) with CodePlex.

Answer (score 0):

[TortoiseGit](http://code.google.com/p/tortoisegit/) is very easy to use to manage GitHub repositories.

To integrate Git with visual studio, you can try [Git Source Control Provider](http://gitscc.codeplex.com/).